# 2 Routers in 1 home?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, webserver, hosting

I want to host a server which requires port forwarding on my home network but I don't want to expose all of my electronics to the open network with forwarding ports and publicly posting my ip address. Can I plug in an extra router I have lying around into my modem and create a second network for just server hosting and whatever I want to do with a seperate ip? Before you tell me that port forwarding is safe, ik it is (99% of the time) but my parents don't believe me lol but they probably would let me do this.

Comment: This depends on your ISP... some will only allow one DHCP address or one MAC address connected to their network. This is a question for your ISP. From a technical standpoint it is simple, connect a small 5-port switch to the modem, then connect the 2 router's Internet/WAN ports to the switch, if your ISP allows it.

Comment: so should i ask if i can have 2 dhcp addresses on my network?

Comment: Honestly, no... Most CSRs would interpret that as meaning in your LAN and answer yes. You need to ask if you can have 2 routers connected to their modem and will each gets own public IP address, that answer will vary by ISP but as a general rule only one device or public IP supported for residential service (at least in our area).

Comment: Wouldn't a better option here just be to use a decent IDS/firewall? You shouldn't be sketchy about forwarding ports, just dmz to the server. It will send all incomming traffic to the designated ip.